# Add repository plugin for Gradle IntelliJ Plugin project

Tags: maven, intellij-plugin

Reading IntelliJ [documentation](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html) it's not quite clear how I add a plugin dependency for GoLand so that I can start creating plugin for that IDE. Apparently I'm supposed to put

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.go</depends>
```

into `plugin.xml`, but it highlights it red - for some reason there's no clear information on how to add this module for use.

**How do I add the Go module to the plugin project?**

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using Gradle as your build system, with the `gradle-intellij-plugin`.
Then, tell Gradle about the Go plugin.
In your `build.gradle`:

```
intellij {
    plugins 'org.jetbrains.plugins.go:193.5233.102.83'
}
```

where you have to explicitly list the version you want to use.

---

From the page in the IntelliJ Dev Guide on [Configuring Plugin Projects Targeting GoLand](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/products/goland.html?search=golan#configuring-plugin-projects-targeting-goland):

> Plugin projects for GoLand can be developed using IntelliJ IDEA with the `gradle-intellij-plugin`.

and

> The Go plugin version is explicitly declared because it isn’t bundled with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition. Select a [version](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go/versions) of the Go plugin compatible with the IntelliJ Idea Ultimate version.

---

**NB**: When using Kotlin Gradle DSL, place the following in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
intellij {
    setPlugins("org.jetbrains.plugins.go:193.5233.102.83")
}
```